# Changing underline color in IE

Tags: html, css

I have text editor which user can play around.  In that I have an IE underline color issue. Below code

```
test <font color="#4ab948"><u>paragraph</u></font>
```

will applied color for text and underline. If user choose underline first then color, the code generated as below which will not apply color for underline :(

```
test <u><font color="#4ab948">paragraph</font></u>
```

Any luck ?

Comment: `<font>` has been deprecated and should not be used....so that's your first problem.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do here.  But, if the user does things in the wrong order, they may get undesirable results.  All you can do is manually flop the order.

Comment: You should just use a <span> and fill all the attributes in one place.

Comment: I think this question may have been written in 1999 and just published now.

Comment: what is it you look for  same color and underline color, or 2 differnt colors ? Anyhow, you should use a span + class (or if any means : em or strong tags).

Answer (score 0):

`font` has been deprecated for a while now. Instead you should use `span` with the style attributes applied to the `span`. For example:

```html
<span style='color:#4ab948;text-decoration:underline;'>paragraph</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want absolute control of the `text-decoration` property on the `u` element...override it with a pseudo-element.

```css
u {
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  color: red;
}
u:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background: green;
  margin-top: -2px;
}
```

```html
<u>paragraph</u>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can come up with two approaches

**Using border-bottom** as

```
span {
color: red;
text-decoration: none;
border-bottom: 1px solid green;
}
```

OR

**using a-span Approach** as

```
a {
  color: green;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
span {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```